# $\Delta$-complex example

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, simplicial-complex

Consider the following $\Delta$-complex homeomorphic to a torus, where the edges with the same orientation (*i.e.* the left and right sides of the square, and the upper and lower ones) are identified:

[image]

In some notes I'm reading it's stated that it's an example of a **regular** $\Delta$-complex, but I cannot see how it's possible.

Comment: Can you please define regular Delta-complex? Could this possibly mean regular CW complex?

Comment: Sure @Matt, I've omitted the definition because I supposed it was standard: by the notes I'm reading _a Δ-complex $X$ is called regular if every $k$-cell in $X$ has $k+1$ distinct vertices, for all $k$_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the definition you've written, it doesn't seem to be regular - after identifying edges, there are only two distinct vertices. Therefore any $2$-cells can't possibly have three distinct vertices.

Comment: Thank you! It's always boring when books/notes contradict themselves.